# Grails 2.4.3: Consume a REST Service

Tags: rest, grails, groovy, basic-authentication

How do I consume a RESTful web service in Grails 2.4.3.  I also need to use Basic Authentication.

You would think there would be an good answer to this question already, but I have really struggled to find one.  Many answers point me in the direction of the Grails rest plugin, which I have tried but could not get to work for me.  I think I am probably just struggling with the docs and using it wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the [REST Client Builder Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder), which was better documented and worked much better for me.  Thanks to Graeme Rocher for that!  Here's a simple example that will hopefully be helpful to others.

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class BatchInstanceService {

    def getBatch(String id) {
        String url = "https://foo.com/batch/$id"

        def resp = new RestBuilder().get(url) {
            header 'Authorization', 'Basic base64EncodedUsername&Password'
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the test class.

```
import grails.test.mixin.*

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus

import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(BatchInstanceService)
class BatchInstanceServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test get batch" () {
        when:
        def resp = service.restart('BI1234')

        then:
        resp.status == HttpStatus.OK.value
    }
}
```

The object returned, `resp`, is an instance of the [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) class.

I really hope this helps.  If there are better examples please post links to them.  Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to pass url parameters other than url string concatenation?

Comment: any answer to the previous question?

Comment: I haven't seen any other way, but I didn't look very hard.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can pass a UrlTemplate-style string and the map of name/value pair url parameters to be substituted.
In addition, there is another shortcut to Auth headers that will auto-encode... so

```
    def urlTemplate = "https://foo.com/batch/{id}"
    def params = [id: $id]

    def resp = new RestBuilder().get(urlTemplate, params) {
       auth username, password
    }
```